# Remote Desktop disconnects after closing my Laptoplid

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop, android, wake-on-lan, hosting

I am searching for a way to host my own laptop and turn it in smth like a VPS, I have watched plently YT tutorials but none of them could help me out. Every Remote Desktop connection that I've started through my Phone disconnects insantly after closing my laptop lid. I've tried [RD Client for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.android&hl=de&gl=US), [Reemo](https://reemo.io/) and [Parsec](https://parsec.app/) but all of them instantly disconnect after closing the laptop lid. I've also informed myself about the WOL (Wake on Lan) feature but that also barely turns on my laptop and also just starts my Laptop if it's open. It would be really nice if someone knows a way to host my own Laptop and helps me out. These are my laptop stats:

- Windows 11 Pro 22H2
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz   1.80 GHz
- Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620
- Ram 8,00 GB
- Phone to remote access is on Andoid 12

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ibo

Comment: Normally in Windows you can configure what happens if you close the lid. By default it will enter Stand-by. If you change it to nothing the connection will persist.

Comment: Might want to turn off the screen when closing lid (when that is set to 'do nothing'), or it'll get toasty: https://superuser.com/questions/994507/disable-laptop-screen-when-lid-is-closed

Comment: Long term consider a dock which allows you to work with the lid closed and with no harm to the laptop.

Comment: Tysm @Robert , MiG and John for telling me about the setting to tell the laptop what to do after closing the Lid. My actual problem is that after I close the Lid I still see the my Desktop but I can't click anything from my Remote Desktop Client, I can only move my mouse. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

As some commenters have already noted, Windows puts laptops into sleep mode by default when the lid is closed. You should be able to [change this](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/keep-windows-laptop-awake-lid-closed/), after which remote access should work as expected. Your laptop will now continue to run as normal, even with the lid closed. (Ideally, you'd choose to simply turn off the screen instead of going to sleep.)

In case the above link breaks, here's the executive summary:

1. Open Power Options in the Control Panel, and select "Choose what closing the lid does" (or just search for this setting from the Start menu).
2. Under "When I close the lid," choose the "Do nothing" option when plugged in.
3. Save and close, and you're good to go!

Do note that this means you may need to manually sleep or shut down if you want to use the laptop as a proper portable device in the future (i.e. you can't just close it and put it in a backpack, as it might keep running).

Also, you may want to be sure your laptop supports proper battery management before using it as a server. When left plugged in, some laptops (and also phones) will just keep trying to charge their batteries, causing them to eventually swell or even explode. I'm aware that certain Lenovo laptops, in particular, support this feature, but you should probably do some research on yours.

Comment: Ty for showing me how to change this setting and also for telling me about the risks, I will probably buy a dock to stay safe. I just came up with a new issue, I can see my Desktop through the Remote Desktop Client and also move my mouse but I can't click anything, it feels like all the clicks that I've made will only take effect after I open my Laptop again.

PS: Sorry for my bad English, it's my third language

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the tip! Updated.

Comment: @Sneazy好 (I'm not sure if this counts as accept begging given that I'm not the post author) If you think this answer helped, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Sneazy好 That might be a good topic for a different question, and unfortunately it's one that I'm not particularly familiar with. An initial guess is that, even though the laptop itself is still powered on, the screen might disable itself when the lid is closed? Again, though, I'd suggest asking a new question to properly follow up on this.

Answer (score 0):

I used one of the "false" HDMI plugs. Then changed display to "only show on 2". Now I can close my lid and fully use laptop.