# Keep remote access software working when laptop lid closes

Tags: windows, windows-11, remote-access, anydesk

I'm using Anydesk to remotely access a Dell XPS 15 with Windows 11 (not sure if this is Windows 11 specific). Lately, the remote screen freezes when the lid is being closed, as soon as the laptop screen turns off (close lid actions are deactivated in the power setting). A few days ago it used to work or I'm doing something different that I didn't realize.

Please note: it's just the remote screen that freezes, the laptop keeps running and the remote control of the mouse and keyboard still works. When reopening the lid, all movement/clicks done with the keyboard and mouse were executed.

The first time it didn't work I opened the power settings, afterward, it seemed to work, but this doesn't fix it anymore. Is anyone else experiencing this kind of behavior? Is there a fix or workaround except for [breaking the ACPI Lid driver](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/bwwet9/anydesk_fast_remote_desktop_app_fails_to_respond/) or [removing the magnet](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2234833-closing-laptop-lid-breaks-remote-control-program)? I also tried to [set the presentation mode](https://superuser.com/a/994525/201818), but it didn't work.

Comment: Trying using a dock and then the lid can be closed and the machine runs fully ON.  I think you may be suspending the machine.

Comment: @John thanks for the suggestion, suspension is definitely off, what about a docking station that makes the machine continue to run? The additional graphic display? Does it need to have a monitor attached?

Comment: You can attach a laptop to a dock, start it , and run it closed. You can add an external monitor if you want, or access it with Remote Desktop Connection

Comment: Thanks, I understand what I have to do, but why exactly does it work with a docking station and not without one?

Comment: You would need to start it locally and then leave it run for later access. Be sure Battery Threshold is on if you will leave it running for long periods of time

Comment: The laptop is kept being connected to the power (via USB C power adapter)...  please see my updates to the question.

Comment: So is mine. But I use Battery Threshold to protect the battery.

Comment: This is happening because AnyDesk is utilizing your built-in  display for graphics output. You can probably solve this problem by installing a HDMI Dummy plug which will emulate an active display even when the lid is closed: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Headless-Display-Emulator-Headless-1920x1080-generation/dp/B06XT1Z9TF/ref=sr_1_2_sspa?keywords=hdmi+dummy+plug&qid=1662646063&sprefix=hdmi+dummy%2Caps%2C258&sr=8-2-spons&psc=1&smid=A1TMR13EX433OS

Answer (score 1):

If and when (as stated above) power Suspension is disabled for the lid closing action, then the issue deals with the display driver not being registered anymore by the machine (and thus, the display picture is not send anymore to the driver and hence cannot be read by AnyDesk).

One way to solve this is to use a bogus HDMI display (a HDMI plug that mimics a display but with no image at all). It works Ok. Link: [HDMI Dummy Plug,Headless Ghost, Display Emulator](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XT1Z9TF)

A 2nd solution is a bit more obscure but doesn't involve using any additional hardware. You need to break the ACPI driver in Windows' Device Manager by changing ("updating") its driver to a non-compatible one (any one from the list). This way the ACPI function will simply won't work and won't turn off the display.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to resolve this issue is to plugged in a 'false' HDMI plug that tricks the system into thinking I have a secondary monitor attached.

Then by setting my monitor setup to "Second screen only" using <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).