# How to disable the internal monitor of my laptop while closing the lid

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, windows-11, windows-11-preview

Note: [Disable laptop screen when lid is closed](https://superuser.com/questions/994507/disable-laptop-screen-when-lid-is-closed)

Actually, my laptop internal monitor was offing well a while ago. but after update Windows to build 26020, everything broken.

The internal monitor doesn't off anymore! Even the lid is close, mouse cursor still could be going to *deep dark* space, and it bothers clam-shelling by just moving the cursor left.

Normally, Windows should disconnect internal monitor when the lid is close, like while DP monitor turns off. My control panel power plan config is ok.

I found "LidAlwysOpen" registry value. But I tried my 4 monitor keys, and nothing changed.

Maybe some application is preventing it, like PowerToys Awake. but I does not installed applications particular around 26020.

One thing, cable is susceptible. I recently change a monitor cable, HDMI-HDMI-DVI converter to HDMI-DVI. Could these cause problem? But to be true that, my other 3 monitors only connected by C or Wi-Fi should be working normally, wouldn't?

Comment: Windows 11 build 26020 is an Insider version.  Can you see if your computer manufacturer has advanced Power Management drivers and perhaps advanced BIOS (UEFI).  Take great care updating BIOS

Comment: Don't use an Insider build if you want to avoid Windows bugs that were not yet fixed. I recommend going back to the stable channel (not called stable for nothing).

Comment: I mean, is this feature change? or bug? I couldn't found related info

Comment: It is not a bug, but rather you may not have good drivers and your machine may not be keeping up with Windows 11.

Comment: Also you should read the responsibilities Microsoft says are all yours when you use Windows Insider

Comment: As an Insider, you are an unpaid *Beta* tester. You found a bug... Good! Report it to Microsoft, so that others will not suffer from that issue with the *release* vesion.

Comment: That was 26020~26040 bug. I jumped to germanium brunch, and the problem gone. was simple! thank all :)